# How to interpret the given boxplot, when there are large amount of values

Tags: r

So, here is the boxplot:

[image]

How to interpret it? Is it so dense below because there are many data? Is it possible to interpret something out of the data?

[UPDATE] I added a new image, where I subsetted the movies that haven't won anything and compared the plot to that of total average, it looks like the boxplot for non winning movies have less outliers?
[UPDATE2] Here I added two boxplots, that are meant to represent averages per year (for the average ratings)
[image]

So, I am not sure whether they should look like that or I have done something wrong in the calculations. I just applied a function group by year and then the function mean. But I am not sure if the mean is the best function in cases where the numbers are average already. Just want to make sure.

Here is the t-test:
[image]

Here I did what one user suggested ( My interpretation of the suggestion) and got different t test results.

[image]
And my code:

```
XX <-  replicate(n = 10000, expr = mean(sample(
  x = imdb_winners$averageRating, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))
YY <- replicate(n = 10000, expr = mean(sample(
  x = imdb_not_winners$averageRating, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))

t.test(XX, YY)
```

Here the t-value is very large so we cal assume that the awarded actors influence the results. I just want to make sure whether my code looks legit and also what could be the best visualisation for these data that could make it appearant that the data are different. Thanks in advice!

Comment: Maybe try plotting a histogram.  This might provide more clarity.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Context of the data you plotted may help us out. As @Dave2e suggested, it might be helpful plot the data another way (that is, if you have the data).

Comment: I would describe those boxplots as "visually indistinguishable", and interpret it as "no differences apparent from visually examining boxplots".

Comment: what information do you want to get from the boxplot? You cannot just compare it without an aim in mind.....

Comment: As @StupidWolf says, you can't get anything more informative than just a qualitative judgement by comparing the boxplots. If you're looking to see if the set of all movies is significantly different than the subset of movies that haven't won an award in terms of your metric (rating from 1-10?), you should use something like an unpaired two-sample t-test.

Comment: @lincolnck Can I do this test even if one sample is all movies and the other one is the subset?

Comment: @user67 Yes. The interpretation of the test statistic from a t-test is that there is a difference between sample means. In this case, you would have the mean rating of all the movies compared to the mean rating of the movies that haven't won an award.  For the details of the t-test look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting comparison would be to subset your data further and compare winning movies against non-winning movies. In this case, and in what you are currently looking at, you should perform a t-test assuming unequal sample sizes and similar variances.

Comment: @lincolnck I wonder would it be reasonable to compare the rating of the winning movie and the average rating of movies per year? I guess that doesn't sound reasonable. Also, I was wondering if I have these two data, with averages per awarded movie and all the movie ratings, what would be the best visualisation of the data so we could see the patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxplots are used to visually display the spread of your data. The box displays the interquartile range (IQR), or the range of values that cover the 25 percentile (Q1) to 75 percentile (Q3). The whiskers show the minimum (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) and maximum (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR).

Any points that fall outside these whiskers are outliers. From your boxplot, it appears as there are a large number of outliers, however, since your dataset is very large, the distribution is not greatly skewed by their presence (your whiskers and box are fairly symmetrical).

Your boxplot is just one step in understanding the distribution of your data. You can plot a histogram, a Q-Q plot, and calculate some other summary statistics to further understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a ton of outliers. How is the data structured? Are there subgroups to the data? Did you preform a logarithmic transformation to the data (like economic data). To interpret the box plot, it really kind of depends on what you have. The most important part to interpreting outputs is to know your data.

Just from what I can see in the image, I would mention the high number of outliers and maybe speculate as to why depending on what the data represents. I would also mention that there is quite a large difference between the minimum and maximum values but between the 25th and 75th quartiles, the spread is quite a bit smaller. This kind of indicates, again, that there are quite a few outliers that you should pay attention to in any sort of regression analysis. It may be helpful to put this on a histogram (with a kernel density) using gggplot to get another look at what is happening - it may help to make further inferences.

Comment: It is data from imdb database, it corresponds user ratings of the movies. I updated the post.

Comment: Logarithm is generally good to think about, but in this case where the data is in the interval [0, 10] and is *left* skewed, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @GregorThomas But what do you think about these two boxplots? Is it true, that the one representing movies with no awards has less outliers? What does short lines mean?

Comment: I commented on your question regarding my interpretation. As to "what does the short lines mean", I would suggest reading the [Wikipedia page on boxplots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) and the help page `?boxplot` if you don't know what all the parts are. Those short lines are called "whiskers". By default they are 1.5 * the IQR above and below the 25th and 75th percentiles, as explained in lincolnck's answer.

Comment: @GregorThomas I just updated my post with different boxplots,  one of them doesn't look legit, and I am afraid that it's because I tried to apply a mean function to already averaged entries ( imdb ratings).

Comment: @GregorThomas Then what's the best way to determine the mean of the sample if the sample consists of means?

Comment: Adding comments on someone's answer isn't a good way to have a discussion. I'd suggest posting on a forum tailored for *dicussion* about *statistics* - perhaps Reddit. Really, this whole question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it's about interpretation of graphs, not programming. It would be closer to on-topic at stats.stackexchange, but you should phrase it as a question about your goal, not what you see as your immediate next step. I will retract my previous comment - I thought you were comparing a boxplot of means to a boxplot of raw data. If they're both means it's not the worst.